# Eclipse PDT Ant

Tags: php, eclipse, development-environment, eclipse-pdt

I downloaded the Eclipse PDT 2.0 GA release (Eclipse 3.4), however, it doesn't look like the Ant tools are included in this package.  How can I install the eclipse Ant tools (editor, executable, etc...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question.  You need to install the Eclipse Java Development Tools.  These can be found under Ganymede > Java Development > Eclipse Java Development Tools in Help > Software Updates > Available Software.

Answer (score 16):

This drove me crazy a couple days ago. In Galileo the update process is slightly different, which is bad forward design if you ask me (but I digress). Here's how you do it in Eclipse 3.5.

Help > Install New Software

From "Work with:" dropdown  choose "Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo"

Then expand "Programming Languages" and choose "Eclipse Java Development Tools".

You could install a different plugin, but this is the standard Eclipse Install.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're looking for, but here's a list of the Eclipse Ant plugins:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/ant/index.php

Comment: Thanks for looking, I had seen that page but it didn't lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I just had the same problem, and as you said, the Java Development Tools contained Ant.

Once you get Ant up and running, you may run into a related problem - this warning in all your Ant files:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document.

The details are in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363768/disable-dtd-warning-for-ant-scripts-in-eclipse/483260#483260), but the short answer I used was to add this minimal DTD to my build files:

```
<!DOCTYPE project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there ought to be a better option. Ant is a stand-alone tool. You ought not to have to load all the Java tools just to get Ant.