# HTML <!doctype html public "">

Tags: html

One of the new doctype declarations can be specified as:

```
<!doctype html>
```

But recently I came across one which was slightly different (view source on http://html5boilerplate.com/):

```
<!doctype html public "">
```

But I couldn't figure what is it for, public part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed one important character

```
<!doctype html public "✰">
```

Inside the quotes is a star character. They like putting it everywhere. Its valid but not in any way useful :P

Comment: The Easter Bunny Strikes Again

Comment: @Moin yep. their dtd for the page is public and is a star.

Comment: I think so too, it's like a signature or something. but wanted to check, maybe there are some use-cases where it can be useful. But I can't think of any.

Comment: @DmitryF No use at all, the reason the html5 doctype is `<!doctype html>` is because that is the minimum that validates in every browser in usage now. And no browser actually cares what is in it, they just check that it is there.

Answer (score 1):

this is mentioned in the html5boilerplate changelog, do a search for doctype on the page.

Its been done to disable dtd warnings in IDE's like eclipse.

See: [Disable DTD warning for Ant scripts in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363768/disable-dtd-warning-for-ant-scripts-in-eclipse)

Comment: Wrong doctype. He meant in the html

Answer (score 0):

IE10 needs the `PUBLIC ""` to properly treat the page as HTML 5 - at least on the Windows 7 version.

Comment: Are you sure about this? What's your source?

Comment: I made the same experience. Without the ````PUBLIC ""```` IE remains in the IE7-Standards Document Mode.