# Html5boilerplate.com's doctype causes html5 document outliner to throw fatal exceptions

Tags: html, doctype

[PaulIrish.com](http://paulirish.com) and [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com) both by the same person, have the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "✰">
```

I now know [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830454/html-doctype-html-public) BUT, the code in question causes at least one [html5 outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner) to fail with some nasty exceptions. [See for yourself](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/process.py?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhtml5boilerplate.com%2F)

So is this code really valid or is it simply a problem with the outliner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in html5lib. Which I probably ought to fix.